# drupal remove individual paragraph tags of the tokens of my replacement patterns in a View

Tags: 7, views, tokens

I want to **rewrite results** in a View and use **replacement patterns** to do this. The problem is that when I do this the **2 tokens** are displayed in a separate paragraph.

--> [views_conditional][field_blg_inhoud]

What I have now:
Views_conditional text

Field_blg_inhoud text

What I want:
Views_conditional text Field_blg_inhoud text

I think I have to change a lot in my standaard CSS etc. but isn't there an easier way? Can I somehow ignore the

somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could uncheck the standard style settings for "add default classes" for each field.

This should place both tokens in one paragraph if you rewrite them in another field (e.g. global custom text).

[image]